# How do I get python to recognize the Pygame module?

Tags: python, pygame

I installed pygame from source using GitHub, ran setup.py, but when I tried importing Pygame, I got a module not found error. I ran 'sys.path' and one of the outputs was '/Applications/Python 3.7/pygame-master'. So if this the folder where the module is stored, why does python not recognize it as one?

Comment: Without additional info or a full output of the error it is difficult to answer

Comment: The full error is just "ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'Pygame'"

Comment: What OS are you on?  Did you do install with enough permissions to have it work?

Answer (score 0):

run `pip install pygame` in a CMD or Terminal.

here is pygame's github: https://github.com/pygame/pygame

Comment: I was trying to install without pip cause using pip in the past has given me ridiculously high cpu usage when running a pygame file ( > 100%)